# Changing the font size and font style in C# GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface, fonts, size

I am trying to change the font style and size individually in GUI. I want it so that every time I click on the check box the size change and when it is unchecked the size goes back to normal. I need to do the same for font style (Arial, etc) as well.

I need help on coding this part. I am still learning GUI btw.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    private void checkBoxFont_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelTest.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F);
    }
```

Right now, it changes both font and size.

Comment: I am still new to this. I need them to change individually and not at the same time. The way that I have it done is at the same time.

Comment: labelTest.Font = new Font("Arial", labelTest.Font.SizeInPoints);

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static bool switcher = true;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkBoxFont_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switcher = !switcher;

        // Toggle between 12 Arial and 10 Times (or whatever you want).
        checkBoxFont.Font = switcher ? new Font("Times New Roman", 10F) : new Font("Arial", 12F);
    }
}
```

This should alternate between sizes and fonts (sizes and font changes are paired).